# Highlighting the numbers in a TimePicker on selection

Tags: java, android

I have a tablet application that uses TimePickers.  I want it to be easy for users to enter times using the keyboard if they want to.  In a small pilot, some users were having difficulties.  They would click on the times and just start typing.  This didn't work, since the times were already in the boxes and the box did not become highlighted.

I tried `android:selectAllOnFocus="true"` in my xml Layout.  Predictably, this did nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the Java source of the activity that has the TimePicker in it:

```java
/**
 * Check if 'v' is an EditText
 */
private static boolean isEditText(View v) {
    return v instanceof EditText;
}


/**
 * Set selectAllOnFocus(true) for all EditTexts in picker.
 */
private static boolean setTimePickerAutoSelectAll(TimePicker picker) {
    for(View view : picker.getTouchables()) {
        if(isEditText(view)) {
            EditText editText = (EditText) view;
            editText.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Then call `setTimePickerAutoSelectAll` in your `onCreate()`:

```
setTimePickerAutoSelectAll(yourTimePicker);
```